# Can I have multiple database users within WordPress?

Tags: database, wp-config

I want to use more than one database user to overcome the 7500 query database limit. How can I do that using `wp-config.php`?

I want all the users to have the same password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set a random user in your `wp-config.php` for each request:

```
$db_users = array(
    'user_1',
    'user_2',
    'user_3',
);

define( 'DB_USER', $db_users[ array_rand( $db_users ) ] );
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , is that means every call to website will change the user ,

Comment: and if iam importing large scv file , how this code can handling it ?

Comment: Yes, every request will use a random user. Unless your import runs in batches, it will use one user (one request).

Comment: @TheDeadMedic or others - where are passwords brought into the array above and how does the array relate to the define( 'DB_USER' and define( 'DB_PASSWORD' already in the wp_config.php file? I currently have 1 user User_1 with its password defined in the wp_config.php file and want to setup 2 new users User_2 & User_3 with the same password as User_1.

Comment: @geneh56 If the password is the same for all users just use `define( 'DB_PASSWORD',  'password' );` and then the code above to randomly switch the user.